# How can I use "Ctrl" key as both mod key and for regular tasks like ^A, ^C, ^V, ^L etc. in i3 WM?

Tags: debian, i3

I recently installed i3 WM in my Debian-based Linux distribution and it is really good. On the first start of i3 WM, I configured `Mod` key as `Windows` key and after some time I changed it to`Alt`. But again I realised that I am not *really* comfortable with both `Windows` and `Alt`. So I decided to set my `Mod` key as `Ctrl` 
And I realised, *this* is better for my workflow. But now, Unfortunately I can't use `Ctrl` key for other necessary tasks like: `^V`, `^C`, `^V`. `^L` etc.
Which is really annoying.

So can I use `Ctrl` key for both purposes or I am not sure if this is even possible?

Comment: How will your device know which to do? What about mapping the alt to ctrl? (so ctrl and alt are swapped)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor My device is dealing with it in some weird way: The thing is when I copy some text from a web page using `Ctrl+C`it works fine and then I can `Ctrl+Shift+V` in terminal but not in a text editor like Kwrite and also I can't `Ctrl+A` anywhere

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Also when I use `Ctrl+L` on terminal it does nothing and when I `Ctrl+Shift+C` it adjust size

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor And _How_ can I map alt to ctrl?

Comment: It is in the keyboard mappings.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I couldn't find this in my `~/.config/i3/config` and also it is not really a solution because If I have to use alt then I could have changed mod key to alt and Ctrl becomes normal. I think it is impossible to do what I asked in the question

Comment: It is the keyboard settings, not i3. It is only a suggestion, if you don't like the position of the key that you use the most, then swap it with another.